# Mosquitto increase max connections

Tags: debian, mqtt, mosquitto, pam, ulimit

I install mosquitto, and have changed a lot of setting in

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
/etc/sysctl.cnof
/etc/pam.d/common-session
/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
```

Detail changed:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf

fs.file-max=2097152
fs.nr_open=2097152
net.core.somaxconn=32768
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=16384
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=16384
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range='1025 65535'
net.core.rmem_default=262144
net.core.wmem_default=262144
net.core.rmem_max=16777216
net.core.wmem_max=16777216
net.core.optmem_max=16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='1024 4096 16777216'
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='1024 4096 16777216'
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets=1048576
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=15

$ sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf

*       hard    nofile  1048576
*       soft    nofile  1048576
*       hard    nproc   1048576
*       soft    nproc   1048676

$ sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-session
$ sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive

session required pam_limits.so
```

But after done this, mosquitto can still support 1024 connections.

So I use `cat /etc/{pid}/limits` to check the mosquitto's limits

Then I found that mosquitto's limit is still the default

```
Max processes             7968                 7968      processes
Max open files            1024                 4096      files
```

I figured out the mosquitto is nologin user, and cannot trigger the PAM limit configuration. And if I use `prlimit` command to increase the soft openfile limit, the mosquitto can indeed increase the max connections, but is limited by hard limit (4096).

Seems the debian still cannot do this ([Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/454465/make-ulimits-work-with-start-stop-daemon)), so a possible solution is to use `/etc/init/mosquitto.conf`

I do changed the `/etc/init/mosquitto.conf` but it seems not working

```
$ sudo vim /etc/init/mosquitto.conf    
limit nofile 1048576 1048576
limit nproc  1048576 1048576
ulimit -n 1048576 # I do both command, but neither do they works
ulimit -u 1048576
```

Is anyone have any idea to make mosquitto support large amount of connections?

Thanks

PS. test tool: [emqtt benchmark](https://github.com/emqtt/emqtt_benchmark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of study, I finally got an solution: change the init script of mosquitto, and change mosquitto user to root

```
$ sudo vim /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

# change user to root
user root



$ sudo vim /etc/init.d/mosquitto

#! /bin/bash
# Change /bin/sh to /bin/bash for fixing "ulimit -u illegal option" error

set_ulimit () {
    ulimit -f unlimited
    ulimit -t unlimited
    ulimit -v unlimited
    ulimit -n 1048576
    ulimit -m unlimited
    ulimit -u 1048576
}

start)
    ...
    # Update ulimit config in start command
    set_ulimit
    ...
    ;;
  stop)
```

After changed the config, reload systemctl config and restart mosquitto

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service mosquitto stop
sudo service mosquitto start
```

Then the limits is changed!

Comment: There is no reason to run mosquitto as root and it should be discouraged.

Comment: Hi @ralight, thanks for your advise. Do you have another way to do this?

Comment: Running as root makes no difference to limits, they are something applied to the process. You can *start* mosquitto as root, but all the config change does is force mosquitto to remain running as root after it has been started.